# Django - How to automatically reset values of the database column to 0 everyday?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to reset the values of 'today_count' of this table back to 0 everyday at 12:00AM automatically. Is there any way to do this?

```
class HashTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    count = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
    today_count = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Run a celery task every day with `HashTag.objects.update(today_count=0)`.

Comment: I believe that my "today" (GMT+2) is different from yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this hack, you can add field day and every time when you add you should check if today is correct and only after this add, if today is not correct you should set to 1 and update today to right day.